# IS THERE AN OPTION TO KNOW WHERE MY USER URL COME FROM?

Tags: url, tracking, utm, typeform

I am using a typeform.com form, but I want to reduce questions, one of my question is "what is your instagram username", I want to eliminate that question if I have the posibility to catch the URL or Username where it comes from when someone made click at link in my bio.

For example someone click my link at instagram Bio, and i want to grab their username

Answer (score 1):

Typeform allows for "hidden fields", which are basically query parameter values propagated through the URL (for example: `<your>.typeform.com/to/<form_id>?username=<some_value>`). Read more about this here: https://www.typeform.com/help/hidden-fields/

However, you say you want the Instagram username of the person clicking the link, and I don't know if Instagram allows embedding dynamic values in URLs for profile bios. You'll need to contact them for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use hidden fields and name your fields appropriately to match your UTM tags and this will work by default in Forms that are not embedded.

Or you can still use a code snippet to take the UTM tags on an embedded as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491748/capture-incoming-url-parameters-pass-into-a-divs-data-url-attribute/61852244#61852244)